# require_once failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php

The required library class seems to elude two .php files though it is found for the other one. The class (libraries/Database.php) methods are used in footer.php.

The error I receive is this:

> Warning: require_once(libraries/Database.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\PHP\Projects in PHP and MySQL\talkingspace\core\init.php on line 15
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'libraries/Database.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\PHP\Projects in PHP and MySQL\talkingspace\core\init.php on line 15

init.php:

```
<?php
// start session since we use it on every page
session_start();

// config file
require_once('config/config.php');

// helper functions
require_once('helpers/db_helper.php');
require_once('helpers/format_helper.php');
require_once('helpers/system_helper.php');

// for autoload of classes
function __autoload($class_name) {
    require_once('libraries/'.$class_name.'.php');
}
```

The index.php file displays correctly:

```
<?php require('core/init.php'); ?>
<?php
// create Topic object
$topic = new Topic();
// get Template class
$template = new Template('templates/frontpage.php');
// assign vars
$template -> topics = $topic -> getAllTopics();
$template -> totalTopics = $topic -> getTotalTopics();
$template -> totalCategories = $topic -> getTotalCategories();
// display template
echo $template;
```

Its template file

```
<?php include 'includes/header.php'; ?>                         
<ul id="topics">
<?php if ($topics) : ?>
<?php foreach($topics as $topic) : ?>
    <li class="topic">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <img class="avatar pull-left" src="images/avatars/<?php echo $topic -> avatar; ?>" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="topic-content pull-right">
                    <h3><a href="topic.html"><?php echo $topic -> title; ?></a></h3>
                    <div class="topic-info">
                        <a href="topics.php?category=<?php echo urlFormat($topic -> category_id); ?>"><?php echo $topic -> name; ?></a> >> <a href="topics.php?user=<?php echo urlFormat($topic -> user_id) ?>"><?php echo $topic -> username; ?></a> >> Posted on: <?php echo formatDate($topic -> create_date); ?> 
                        <span class="badge pull-right"><?php echo replyCount($topic -> id); ?></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php else : ?>
    <p>No topics to display</p>
<?php endif; ?>
<h3>Forum Statistics</h3>
<ul>
    <li>Total Number of Users: <strong>52</strong></li>
    <li>Total Number of Topics: <strong><?php echo $totalTopics; ?></strong></li>
    <li>Total Number of Categories: <strong><?php echo $totalCategories; ?></strong></li>
</ul>
<?php include 'includes/footer.php'; ?>
```

serves well however a similar template file fails with two other .php files. Here's one (register.php):

```
<?php require('core/init.php'); ?>
<?php
// get Template class
$template = new Template('templates/register.php');
// assign vars
$template -> title = 'Create an Account';
// display template
echo $template;
```

and its template is:

```
<?php include 'includes/header.php'; ?>
    <form role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="register.php">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name<sup>*</sup></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email Address<sup>*</sup></label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email Address">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Choose Username<sup>*</sup></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Create A Username">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Password<sup>*</sup></label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Enter A Password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Confirm Password<sup>*</sup></label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password2" placeholder="Enter Password Again">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Upload Avatar</label>
            <input type="file" name="avatar">
            <p class="help-block"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>About Me</label>
            <textarea id="about" rows="6" cols="80" class="form-control" name="about" placeholder="Tell us about yourself (Optional)"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input name="register" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
    </form>
<?php include 'includes/footer.php'; ?>
```

Please assist. I tried a few solutions posted here to no avail. The XAMPP folder is the default one on C:\ and the project folder is on another drive.

Comment: permission issue may be

Comment: The thing is that same code works for one .php file and won't for two others. If this helps to pin down the issue the instructor had the same issue then he replaced the html code of the template and the issue was gone.

Comment: In init.php? Where should I put it?

Comment: change require_once with require "/path/to/file"

Comment: Could you post the code please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The footer displays correctly on each page with a change in init.php:

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    require_once('/PHP/Projects in PHP and MySQL/talkingspace/libraries/'.$class_name.'.php');
}
```

Inside httpd.conf the default DocumentRoot and Directory are changed to

```
DocumentRoot "D:/PHP"
<Directory "D:/PHP">
```

config.php defines `BASE_URI` as 
`define("BASE_URI", "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/Projects in PHP and MySQL/talkingspace/");`